# Insert records into a table from more than pc at same time

Tags: vb.net

I want to insert from more one pc at the same time into the same table in sql server and vb.net.

Error:

> Conflicts when inserting data at same time

```
Try
    Dim com As New SqlCommand()
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    com.CommandText = "insertooks"

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MULTIINSERT_CODE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MULTIINSERT_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MULTIINSERT_DATE ", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
    com.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    MsgBox("Record inserted successfully")
Catch ex As Exception
    'Throw ex
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
End Try
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE  [dbo].[insertooks]  
   @MULTIINSERT_CODE                    NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   ,    
      @MULTIINSERT_NAME                 NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL   ,    
     @MULTIINSERT_DATE                 DATETIME      = NULL   
AS  
BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON  
 INSERT INTO MULTIINSERT_TB
      (                    
        MULTIINSERT_CODE,  
        MULTIINSERT_NAME,  
       MULTIINSERT_DATE
              
      )

 VALUES 
      ( 
        @MULTIINSERT_CODE  ,
        @MULTIINSERT_NAME ,
        @MULTIINSERT_DATE                
      ) 

 END
```

Comment: Post the actual error message you are receiving.

Comment: So, my gut feeling here, there is something going else on here that such a simple sql insert is causing enough concern to warrant this question.  Truth is conflicts are a fact of life with multi user DBs that can never be TRULY eliminated.  Comes down to dealing with it when it happens. Anyway, I would expect that statement to be done in micro-seconds, so the chances of two users tipping each other up is pretty slim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection object needs to be declared with a `Using` in the method where it is used so it can be closed and disposed.

Use `Using...End Using` blocks to ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed. Note the comma at the end of the `Using`; this includes the command in the the `Using`.

Pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the `CommandText` and the connection directly to the constructor of the command.

This should be `.Add` method which takes the `SqlDbType` as the second parameter. The `.AddWithValue` method (which shouldn't be used with Sql Server) takes the value as the second parameter.

Never show a message box while a connection is open. The user could have gone to lunch and there sits your open connection. Actually, it will eventually time out but you get the point.

I hope the primary key of MULTIINSERT_TB is an identity field (auto-number) and you are not passing a value for it.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub OpCode()
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                com As New SqlCommand("insertooks", con)
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            com.Parameters.Add("@MULTIINSERT_CODE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            com.Parameters.Add("@MULTIINSERT_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            com.Parameters.Add("@MULTIINSERT_DATE ", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            con.Open()
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using 'closes and disposes con and com
        MsgBox("Record inserted successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Throw ex
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```